# Batch Assigning a new variable with added characters to a new variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to say: If this log file already exists in this folder (for example abc.log is already there), tell the user it exists and create the new log file as RED_abc.log.

This is what I've got.

```
set /p answer=1. Please type in a name
if exist %answer%.log (
echo The log file will be called RED_%answer1%.log
set %answer%=RED_%answer%
echo %answer%>>%answer%.log
)
```

It doesn't create the new log file but instead puts the text in the old log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets mean your code is one line. `%var%` are expanded when line is read. Just close the bracket before your last line. Then `%answer%` will contain either the oldname if it didn't exist, or the new name if it did.

To use `%var%` on one line when it changes, you have to turn on a mode with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and refer to ones you want expaneded at runtime via `!var!` syntax. See `SetLocal /?`

```
set /p answer=1. Please type in a name
if exist %answer%.log (
echo The log file will be called RED_%answer1%.log
set %answer%=RED_%answer%
)
echo %answer%>>%answer%.log
```

Assume they type cat

If the log exists %answer% will be set to Red_Cat. However it won't change untill a new line is read. After the bracket it will send either Cat or Red_Cat to a file of same name.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p answer=1. Please type in a name
if exist %answer%.log (
echo The log file will be called RED_%answer1%.log
set %answer%=RED_%answer%
echo !answer!>>!answer!.log
)
```

Note the 2nd last line.

Comment: I did it slightly differently.

I changed the line: set %answer%=RED_%answer%

To: set answer=RED_!answer!
echo %answer1%>>%answer1%.log